# Proof of convergence of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can it be proved analytically that the following series converges to $\bar{y}=\frac{a}{1-b}$ for $t\to\infty$:$$\bar{y}=\frac{a+ab+ab^{2}+...+ab^{t-1}}{1-b^{t}}$$
I see it numerically, but not analytically. Thank you.

Comment: hint: geometric series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can rewrite your equation to see things more clearly:
$$
\bar{y} = \frac{a}{1-b^t} \cdot \left( 1 + b + \cdots + b^{t-1} \right)
$$

Notice that the thing inside the parenthesis is a geometric progression, so applying the formula of the [sum of the geometric series](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Geometric_series#Sum_2) one can get

$$
\bar{y} = \frac{a}{1 - b^{t}} \cdot \frac{1 - b^{t}}{1 - b} = \frac{a}{1-b}
$$